# Excel Boxplot Create a horizontal Line

Tags: excel

is there a way to create a horizontal line in a boxplot?

[image: actual diagram]

so i have this boxplot and i want to get the orange line in the first boxplot with the y-axis 00:30 as a horizontal line. Is that even possible?

Edit:
so i have some data like that:

[image]

and now i want to create a horizontal line which is 30 minutes so my boxplot should look like this:

[image]

so normally it is one boxplot, because i filtered it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested an example with your needs. I used two charts and stacked them on top of each other.
The first graph has your data, while the second graph has the average.(I am not an expert in excel).

**The data**

[image]

**The First graph**

[image]

**The second graph**

In this graph I removed the background (transparent). After "them combination" i removed the axes.

[image]

**The Final Graph**

[image]

Then you can merge the two graphs so they always stay aligned.

Comment: Is there really no better solution to this problem?